# Java MAPI library for Exchange 2010

Tags: java, email, exchange-server, mapi

Is there a Java library which allows to create a new mail with a file attached and brings the mail client (Outlook 2010) to front?

The client and the Exchange 2010 server run on Windows 2008 64 Bit.

Answer (score 1):

[JDIC](http://java.net/projects/jdic/) provides some functionality to do this.  JDIC doesn't play well in OSGi, so I recently extracted the relevant MAPI bits into a bundle called [jmapi](http://github.com/briandealwis/jmapi).